# deploying front end website with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, es6-modules

I just deployed a landing page on GitHub and I'm using html, CSS and JS with modules:

`index.html` uses script of type `module`:

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
...
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js` imports `changeLanguage` function and uses it:

**main.js**

```
import { changeLanguage } from "./modules/changeLanguage":


...
changeDate();
changeTheme();
changeLanguage();
```

in `changeLanguage.js` exporting the necessary function:

**modules/changeLanguage.js**

```
export const changeLanguage = ()=>{
...
}
```

however, when deployed it gaves me an error `Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.`

and  **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () /alarabiya/modules/changeLanguage:1**

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

the issue was that i have to add `.js` extension to the end of the file like this:

```
import { changeLanguage } from "./modules/changeLanguage.js";
```

Comment: Yes, it shall work now.

Comment: damn.. working with react for a long time that i haven't imagined that this would be the issue

Comment: When you use es modules file extensions are required.